# Get x, y values of pixels of certain color with python PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm really struggling with understanding how to manipulate images with PIL. I'm trying to return the x and y coords of all the pixels that match a certain color. So in pseudo-code:

```
img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox)
pixels = img.getdata()
for i in range(len(pixels)):
    if pixels[i] == (255, 0, 0, 255) # red for example:
        coords.append(pixels[i].x)
        coords.append(pixels[i].y)
```

I simply don't know how to do the last bit where you append the x and y. Is there a function for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab

img = ImageGrab.grab()
pixels = img.load()
width, height = img.size
coords = []
for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
        if pixels[x, y] == (255, 0, 0):
            coords.append((x, y))
```

Comment: Thanks you... Can't believe i didn't realize you could do that